# Auto repeat FadeOut after FadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("button.art").click(function() {
        $(".patr").fadeIn("slow");
        $("button.art").text("Hide them all").promise().done(function(){

        $("button.art").click(function() {
        $(".patr").fadeOut().promise(); 
            $("button.art").text("Show them all").promise();
        })  })   })  });
```

I have a few squares in a class "patr".
When I press the button I want to show them and to change the text from "show them all" to "hide them all".

When I press the button again, I want to do the reverse, to hide the squares and to change the text from "hide them all" to "show them all" so that to can be done again and again.

The problem is that after first show - hide cicle, the fadeOut function start automatic.

What I'm doing wrong?
Here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=gndOED4Qiq

EDIT:
Another more simple and correct version:

```
    $("document").ready(function () {
    $("button.art").click(function () {
        $(".patr").fadeToggle();
        if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
            $(this).text('Hide Them All');
            $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Well that fiddle seems to be empty.

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Comment: Yes Felix. I used the way that you see in my first post (after edit) but your answer helped me a lot to understand. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shorten your code using **[.fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)** to toggle between fade in and fade out animation as well as using ternary operator to set the text of your button:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("button.art").click(function () {
        $(".patr").fadeToggle("slow");
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).text(text == "Hide them all" ? "Show them all" : "Hide them all");
    })
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jf9sV/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Kwj9/1/)**

This is how i did: make to function, am setting class ie show_cls, hide_cls

```
$("#myBotton_div").on('click', '.show_cls', function () {
        $(".patr").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).text("Hide them all");
        $(this).removeClass('show_cls');
        $(this).addClass('hide_cls');
    });

    $("#myBotton_div").on('click', '.hide_cls', function () {
        $(".patr").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).text("Show them all");
        $(this).removeClass('hide_cls');
        $(this).addClass('show_cls');
    });
```